# Redirect wildcard domain to another one in nginx

Tags: redirects, web-hosting, 301-redirect, nginx

I have two websites `*.env1.example` and `*.env2.example`, I want to redirect all traffics in `env1` to `env2`, how to do so in Nginx?

I do redirect from one specific domain to another, but now I want to redirect all domains `*.env1.example` to `*.env2.example`

Comment: When you say "from one specific domain" does that mean that you already are redirecting `http://env1.example/` to `http://env2.example/` just not all the wildcard subdomains?

Comment: Do you already have the wildcard DNS records set up for the two domains and pointing to your server?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I mean I did redirect from abc.env1.example to abc.env2.example and that works fine but I need to redirect all subdomains. and yes I have DNS records for the two domains (*) and pointing to servers (each one pointing to a different server)

Comment: Did you already configure your virtual hosts in your web server configuration for the wildcard subdomains? It sounds like you intend to have them all pointing to the same document route